# need to return empty string row instead of null row in below sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Apple,Orange,Mango,Grapes','[^,]+',1,level) regexp_substr

FROM dual

  CONNECT BY level<=regexp_count('Apple,Orange,Mango,Grapes',',')+1;
```

This will return 
Result:
Apple
Orange
Mango
Grapes

If we pass empty string

```
SELECT regexp_substr('','[^,]+',1,level) regexp_substr

FROM dual

  CONNECT BY level<=regexp_count('',',')+1;
```

it returns 
Result:
(null)

I want the result as -1 if null is output.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In oracle NULL is treated as an empty string  (blank)

Comment: In that case can I get some other string like -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you could use You can use NVL for check null value and obtain a value eg:

```
 NVL(regexp_substr('','[^,]+',1,level)), -1)
```

or

```
 NVL(regexp_substr('','[^,]+',1,level)), '-1')
```